# Initializing an array of Doubles in Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift

I can initialize an array of `Int`s in Swift 4 as follows:

```
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let intArray = Array(1...10)
```

If I specify the array as an array of `Double`s like so:

```
let doubleArray1: [Double] = Array(1...100)
```

...the compiler says:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Array' to specified type '[Double]'

If I try this:

```
let doubleArray1 = Array<Double>(1...100)
```

...the compiler says this...

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Array' with an argument
>   list of type '(CountableClosedRange)'

I got it to work using `map`, as follows:

```
// [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
let doubleArrayMap = Array(1...10).map{Double($0)}
```

Is there a "cleaner" way to quickly initialize an array of `Doubles` **without using `map`** in Swift?

Comment: a Range can only work with discrete values

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can initialize an array from the sequence produced by `stride()`:

```
let doubles = Array(stride(from: 1.0, through: 100.0, by: 1.0))
```

But keep aware of the restricted floating point precision:
If the  increment is not an integral value then rounding errors can
accumulate. Mapping (and scaling) an integer range would then be
the safer solution.

Comment: Perfect! I'll accept once the timer goes off. Thank you!